# $i^3=1$, this must be false but

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

Ok this is quite dumb and absurd but it goes like this:

$i^3 = (i^4)^{3/4}= 1^{3/4} = 1$

I am not very sure what the mistake is, maybe if this was true we contradict $(i^4)^{3/4} \neq (i^{3/4})^3$

Comment: Fractional powers of complex numbers do not immediately make sense; see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84781/10513). (Or just remember that $1^{1/2}=\pm1$.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the Laws of Rational Exponents?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628759/what-are-the-laws-of-rational-exponents) also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-cdot-1-neq-sqrt-12?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/simple-complex-number-problem-1-1?noredirect=1&lq=1, ....

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can find many other questions here illustrating how $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ fails for complex numbers.